# What'd the behaviour be when 2 lambdas has the same kinesis stream?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

Let's say I have a 2 Lambdas, `LambdaA` and `LambdaB`. Both the lambdas are *independent* lambdas which have *different* functions in them. I also have a Kinesis called `KinesisA` which is a data stream *without* setting anything to its consumer option.

What will the behaviour be like if I add `KinesisA` to the stream trigger of `LambdaA` and `LambdaB`?

Will the messages from `KinesisA` be round-robined between the 2 lambdas or will both of the lambdas *each* receive a same *copy* of the messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shortly; each consumer will have the same copy of the message while they are consuming the kinesis stream. There is an individual iterator age for each kinesis consumer (by default 24 hours - up to 7 days).

Means that if one of your lambda doesn't consume and 10 hours later start to consume he will consume the stream from where he left.

You may configure different batch size for each consumer (one lambda may have 25, other is just 1)

Comment: That’s interesting. I’m assuming this is the case even without using the fan-out setting? And is there a limitation to how many individual different Lambda consumers can consume from the same Kinesis to each get their own copy of the same message?

Comment: As far as i know there is no limit for consumers but for read requests and it is related to shard count; `Each shard can support up to five read transactions per second. Each read transaction can provide up to 10,000 records with an upper quota of 10 MB per transaction.`